# "Interface" in MDN documentation for JS?

Tags: javascript, browser, interface

I have come across word "**interface**" so many times while reading through MDN documentation for JS, but never fully understood what does it refer to.

I know that there is no such thing as 'interface' in JS like in Java, C#, TypeScript and all other similar OOP languages.

As I know so far, an interface is just a collection of properties and methods definitions (not implementations) that a certain class must implement in order to conform to a particular interface, but that is not, once again, case for JS.

Now, let's imagine that MDN says some property of some object, let's say `geolocation` property of `window.navigator` returns `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` object. Then we read that these objects are conform to `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` interface(s).

Checking `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` interfaces through `console.dir` returns that they are functions. So, does it mean that `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` objects returned by accessing `geolocation` property on `window.navigator` are just objects created by `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` functions?

So, does term `interface` on MDN documentation just refers to function, which creates objects with a certain properties  and methods just like regular constructor functions?

Then why I can't generate a new `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` object(s) using these `GeolocationPosition/GeolocationPositionError` functions and `new` operator?

Comment: Interfaces do not need to be literally supported in code, they just need to be *specified* somewhere in order to be useful. Even if Javascript doesn't have anything called `interface`, the documentation and *specification* can still talk about interfaces for the purpose of describing how things are expected to behave.

Comment: Thanks. So, it might be just for the purpose to be understandable and descriptive for people coming, for instance, from other programming languages yeah?

Comment: Why can't it be for the purpose to be understandable and descriptive, period?

Answer (score 4):

Interface actually has a well defined meaning in the context of browser web APIs.

An interface in that context is a [WebIDL](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/) interface. WebIDL is the "interface specification language" on top of which things like HTML and the DOM specifications are built on.

For example `window.navigator` implements the [navigator](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#dom-navigator) interface:

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface Navigator {
  // objects implementing this interface also implement the interfaces given below
};
Navigator includes NavigatorID;
Navigator includes NavigatorLanguage;
Navigator includes NavigatorOnLine;
Navigator includes NavigatorContentUtils;
Navigator includes NavigatorCookies;
Navigator includes NavigatorPlugins;
Navigator includes NavigatorConcurrentHardware;
```

---

Interfaces are similar to what you would expect from "OO languages":

> IDL fragments are used to describe object oriented systems. In such systems, objects are entities that have identity and which are encapsulations of state and behavior. An interface is a definition (matching interface InterfaceRest) that declares some state and behavior that an object implementing that interface will expose.

> An interface is a specification of a set of interface members (matching InterfaceMembers). These are the members that appear between the braces in the interface declaration.

> Interfaces in Web IDL describe how objects that implement the interface behave. In bindings for object oriented languages, it is expected that an object that implements a particular IDL interface provides ways to inspect and modify the object’s state and to invoke the behavior described by the interface.

> An interface can be defined to inherit from another interface. If the identifier of the interface is followed by a U+003A COLON (":") character and an identifier, then that identifier identifies the inherited interface. An object that implements an interface that inherits from another also implements that inherited interface. The object therefore will also have members that correspond to the interface members from the inherited interface.

All from the WebIDL specification.

As for why you can't generate your own instances of the implementations browser provide for those interfaces?

I suspect `GeolocationPositionError` for example cannot be created because it is not exposed on `window`. If allowing that is useful to users you are welcome to open a feature request in the [whatwg/html](https://github.com/whatwg/html) repo.

Answer (score 2):

In the MDN docs, the word *interface* is often being used to talk about [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) (Application Programming Interface). Indeed, the only thing you have to worry about as a developer is the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) (not the implementation details behind the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)).

Interfaces are only conceptual in JavaScript but they exist in some extending languages like TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard many times that there is no need to look into the implementation details (that is why we actually need abstraction), but, I think, sometimes it is really good to understand how things actually work (at least to better understand official docs. and not rely only on YouTube tutorials).

Comment: With a well-documented interface it's often needless to look at the implementation, but nothing prevents you from reading the source code of open source web engines like [chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) if you need to look what's under the hood and explain some unknown behavior.

Comment: @GuerricP chromium actually includes webidl interfaces in its source code. As a protip source.chromium.org is a much nicer code search than github (although the new search beta is an improvement)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum indeed https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/document.idl thanks I didn't know that